# is it safe to perform file operations on a background NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsoperationqueue

The question says it all, I cannot find an answer, but I want to be sure before I ship code.

Comment: I know that cocoa can get upset with things like ui and coredata being on different threads, and i just want to make sure.

Comment: Only UI; I don't think Core Data is any different to any other multi-threaded synchronization issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can perform file operations on the background queues. Obviously you should avoid modifying files that you might be actively using in other queues, but generally it's perfectly acceptable.

Downloading content into files is one of the most common background operations out there.